# If there is a dictionary translating 1:1 a word in english to a word in another language

Tags: discussion, translation

When you look up a word in the dictionary you usually get a **long** *sentence* rather than 1 word. For example:

> **word**: a single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing, used with others (or sometimes alone) to form a sentence and typically shown with a space on either side when written or printed.

I am wondering if there is a dictionary that simply translates 1:1 words, that is free, public domain, and available for download as computer text of some sort. For example, it would be a list like this:

```
word,palabra
hello,hola
cow,vaca
...
```

Wondering if any such *simple* translation resource exists. I know you can get this info from Google Translate, but it costs money to do in bulk.

I am interested in any language, particularly the major ones listed in Google Translate.

Comment: some word have no direct translation, or have several different meanings each with a different translation.

Comment: Word-by-word translations very often end up in something that makes no sense in the resulting language. However, it sounds like what you're looking for is a [bilingual dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilingual_dictionary), something that's available in just about any bookstore. (And I'm sure online too.)

Comment: There’s google translate.

Comment: @Lawrence — Oh you are a wag!

Comment: Buy the smallest cheapest (most useless) pocket dictionary you can find. That will probably do the job. From your bio I assume you want to incorporate it into a computer program, so you’ll have to OCR it. Of course you realize GIGO.

Comment: No, because languages aren’t 1:1 in either lexicon or grammar. If they were, translation wouldn’t be such a big task.

Comment: You make fun of these 1:1 dictionaries, but this is exactly what Wiktionary is.

Comment: @LancePollard not exactly. Wiktionary gives you (after definitions) a word or phrase per language for each definition editors have listed: [example from my answer](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bow); the single word translations link to the definitions. If the OP wants to do something automatic, parsing the list of lists would be very challenging

Answer (score 9):

It's never going to work, even for simple words and applications. Think of *bow* for example. Many meanings, some of which don't have single word translations in other languages (e.g. [French](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/bow)). I chose this example because even a five year old would use at least three distinct meanings, including some that translate to a phrase.

That said, [translatr](https://translatr.varunmalhotra.xyz/) is probably your best bet (it's hard to search for because Google assumes you've misspelt "translate" and points you to its own tool). For my example above, fed simply "bow" and told to give me French, it returns just "arc". Fine if you're doing archery, or referring to rainbows, not much use if you're taking about the front of a ship, or a decoration on a present.

Comment: ...or, indeed, if you're talking about an act of obeisance (which is also a noun).